# PHP/HTML Getting the array multiple and storing into an array to sum them up

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have a form here, I have set the checkbox value to that of the respective pricing of that product. The textbox is for users to key in the quantity they want. In my PHP file, then I would compute the total amount submitted in an order form but I can't seem to get it right. The name of my checkboxes is "prodID[]" and that of my textboxes is "prodQty[]". The code below is what I have done in my php file.

```
echo '<td width="200px"><input name="prodID[]" id="'.$row['prodAmt'].'" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['prodAmt'].'">';      
echo '<input name="prodQty[]" type="hidden" value="0"><input name="prodQty[]" id="'.$row['prodID'].'" type="text" size="1" value="" >';
```

[image]

```
$orderQty[] = $_POST['prodQty'];
$orderAmt[] = $_POST['prodID'];

for ($i=0; $i < count($orderQty); $i++) {
    $multiple[$i]=$orderQty[$i]*$orderAmt[$i];
}
$amount = array_sum($multiple);
```

Comment: Your checkboxes will either return a value if they are checked or will be ignored when they are unchecked. You will not get a NULL, FALSE or other value, where all your text boxes return value even if empty. So you may have to use some other method to find out which check box correspond to which text.

Comment: Can you provide an example `$POST` output? Are the `$orderAmt` values numeric? It comes from `$_POST['prodID']` so it seems strange that you could be using it in the `$amount` calculation unless it is the cost of the product. BTW, it is redundant to have a checkbox and qty text for each product. Ie if a qty > 0 in the text then does it matter if the checkbox is selected?

Comment: Yes, I have defined that textboxes' value="0" as a hidden input, and will be written over if the user keys in data into the textbox. I set my prodAmt as the value for my checkboxes, so the checkboxes correspond to the price of that product. @bansi

Comment: $orderAmt is numeric, and yes I initially set the value of the checkbox as the prodID but I decided I'd set the value as prodAmt instead because then I do not have to run through the database to get the respective prodAmt for the prodID again. Oooh, you make a pretty good point using just textboxes. Even so I still have to run through the database to get the value of prodAmt out again and I'd still be faced with the same problem. The thing is, it actually allows me to key in Qty for only A1, and the calculation is correct, but just only for A1. @Tristan

Comment: `Id x Qty` ?? doesnt look right to me

Comment: the 'ID' value is the respective pricing. It is actually Qty * Price. Sorry for the confusion @Andrew

Comment: @Jeany sry, then that looks legit to me :/

Comment: maybe if you post more codes, then we can spot something wrong about it

Comment: I just posted the relevant HTML code just before the image @Andrew

Comment: Just a wild guess,  the total element in ur qty array is not the same as id array??

Comment: It is the same, the items in the products table has alr been inserted into the database, its just calling the amount out, so that I can compute the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add it while looping?

```
 $multiple+=$orderQty[$i]*$orderAmt[$i];
```

Comment: Unsupported operand type @monace19

Comment: initialize $multiple=0;

Comment: try:  $multiple= $multiple + $orderQty[$i]*$orderAmt[$i];